# Unity Spawn-Manager with Waves

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, spawn

I'm new and try to make my project from beginning.

I made a random Spawn position, an `IEnumerator` to wait between waves.
The problems are:

1. Enemies (10) spawn at the same point
2. After `waveNum` increases, the enemy count doesn't reset
3. It don't spawn new Enemies

Here's the code to generate random spawn position for enemies:

```
private Vector3 GenerateSpawnPos(){

    float spawnPosX = Random.Range(-spawnRange, spawnRange);
    float spawnPosZ = Random.Range(-spawnRange, spawnRange);

    Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(spawnPosX, 0.91f, spawnPosZ);

    return spawnPos;}
```

This is the `IEnumerator`:

```
private IEnumerator WaitAndSpawn() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    Spawn();}
```

And the last Spawn:

```
private void Spawn(){

    int index = Random.Range(0, enemys.Length);
    Vector3 enemySpawn = GenerateSpawnPos();
    while (Vector3.Distance(player.position, enemySpawn) < treshhold)
    {
        enemySpawn = GenerateSpawnPos();
    }
    for (; enemyCount > 0; enemyCount--)
    {
        Instantiate(enemys[index], enemySpawn, enemys[index].transform.rotation);
    }
    if (enemyCount == 0)
    {
        enemyCount = 10;
        waveNumber++;
    }
}
```

[image: Start and Update]
My goal is to spawn enemys at random location + outside the radius of player (*4) and spawn timer should be 10 seconds between waves. *for test i made 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawn logic has a couple of problems.
You use several loops which has no sense.
Spawn logic:

1. loop x times
2. inside loop generate position and instantiate

Please see the following code:

```
  private void Start()
  {
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnWave", 0, 2);
  }

  private void SpawnWave()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++)
    {
      int index = Random.Range(0, enemys.Length);

      Vector3 position = GenerateSpawnPos();

      Instantiate(enemys[index], position, enemys[index].transform.rotation);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thx, I made close to yours.

Comment: Still you need the index logic inside the loop.
See my answer and please accept it if it helped you.

Comment: Logic for *while* loop is for check if enemy spawn near player, if yes dont spawn